# How to show "edit image" in Sitecore experience editor?

Tags: sitecore

In sitecore "content editor" we can use the "image editor" by clicking "edit image" in the data section, but in the experience editor it is not visible.
is there a way to make available for editors to use the image editor? or this behavior is a sitecore standard?
thanks for help
[Picture field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpVyA.jpg)

Comment: I have the same issue when you try to edit File and Droplist field types in experience editor.

Answer (score 1):

I've just written it up in a [blog post](http://sitecoreandmore.blogspot.com.au/2016/09/adding-button-to-experience-editor-to.html).

First you'll need to add a new button under

```
/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Image/WebEdit Buttons
```

You can duplicate one of the existing ones and change the icon and text yourself.  Make the contents of the **Click** field:

```
chrome:field:editcontrol({command:"webedit:changeimage"})
```

(there's already a `webedit:editimage` so we can't name it that).

Open `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` and duplicate the entry for `webedit:chooseimage`.  Change the command name to `webedit:changeimage` as per above. Then change the type to the class you will create below.

If you have access to a decompiler, take a look at the existing command `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Shell.EditImage` as well as the existing command
for selecting an image in Experience Editor `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.ChooseImage`.  You'll see that they're similar, but unfortunately they use two different
methods of opening a dialog (`Windows.RunApplication` and `SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog`) so we can't reuse the existing class as-is.  I have created a class that uses a bit of both (link below).

Create your class (eg. EditImage.cs), make it serializable and inherit from WebEditImageCommand like the other EE buttons. I have posted the [full class as a gist](https://gist.github.com/moo2u2/f49e110beab33a15935b3fc6f31e4c2d) for you.

When you select an image in the Experience Editor, you should now have an extra button in the list which opens the image editor in a modal window when clicked.

Comment: thanks Jason for your answer I could do it simply by enabling the check box (Show in field editor) for the item (Edit image):
/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Image/

Comment: Checking 'show in field editor' on Edit Image didn't seem to do anything for me, what version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do next steps, is not the most elegant way but you can do it:

In the Experience Editor, click the image that you want to edit, and in the floating toolbar that appears, click More and then Edit the related item. This opens the item in the Content Editor, from where you can scroll to the field that contains the image and click Edit image.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I want to show for the editors the same options as in the content editor.